# Powershell Json replacing — with â

Tags: json, powershell, character-encoding

I have a script that gets data from a public API. I try to parse a value from the Json response into a variable. However it seems that when I `Write-Host` the variable it has replaced — with â.

**Code:**

```bsh
$SetData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/2XM.json" -ContentType "application/json" -Method GET

$Card = $SetData.data.cards | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "Adaptive Automaton" -and $_.isPromo -ne "true"}
Write-Host $Card.type -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

**Output:**

`Artifact Creature â€” Construct`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the strings returned by the Invoke-RestMethod here are encoded in 'ISO-8859-1' and not as you would expect in UTF-8.

This means you need to convert to UTF-8 where needed, something like this:

```
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('ISO-8859-1')

$SetData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/2XM.json" -ContentType "application/json" -Method GET

$Card = $SetData.data.cards | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "Adaptive Automaton" -and !$_.isPromo}
# convert the string in '$Card.type' from encoding 'ISO-8859-1' into 'UTF-8'
$cardType = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8).GetString($encoding.GetBytes($Card.type))

Write-Host $cardType -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

Output

```
Artifact Creature — Construct
```

---

To convert the whole json to UTF-8, You could use `Invoke-WebRequest` rather than `Invoke-RestMethod`:

```
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('ISO-8859-1')

$SetData = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/2XM.json" -Method Get
# convert $SetData.Content to UTF-8 and convert that from JSON
$content = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8).GetString($encoding.GetBytes($SetData.Content)) | ConvertFrom-Json

$Card = $content.data.cards | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "Adaptive Automaton" -and !$_.isPromo}
Write-Host $Card.type -ForegroundColor Cyan
```